# comportamento de containers aninhados

Tags: html5, flexbox, css-display

Porque o `text-align=center` de um *container* reflete também em seu *container* interno?

```css
.container-externo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-interno {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-externo">
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A sigla CSS significa *Cascading Style Sheet*, ou seja, estilos em cascata. O que te fez pensar que o elemento interno não teria o estilo aplicado no elemento externo?

Comment: Sou aprendiz. Mas obrigado por me fazer enxergar a obviedade!

Answer (score -1):

o CSS funciona em cascata, ou seja, os filhos de seus elementos irão receber os mesmos estilos que seu pai recebeu (as estilizações divs dentro da div container-interno afeta a div container-externo).
Para mudar isso, basta ir no código e estilizar o texto lá dentro como você fez com a outra div.

```css
.container-externo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-interno {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left; // modificação
}
```

```html
<div class="container-externo">
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
  <div class="container-interno">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!